# replace missing values in categorical data

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data, categorical-data

Let's suppose I have a column with categorical data "red" "green" "blue" and empty cells

```
red
green
red
blue
NaN
```

I'm sure that the NaN belongs to red green blue, should I replace the NaN by the average of the colors or is a too strong assumption? It will be

```
col1 | col2 | col3
  1      0     0
  0      1     0
  1      0     0
  0      0     1
 0.5    0.25  0.25
```

Or even scale the last row but keeping the ratio so these values have less influence? Usually what is the best practice?

```
 0.25  0.125  0.125
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do with the data.
Is the average of these colors useful for your purpose?
You are creating a new possible value doing that, that is probably not wanted. Especially since you are talking about categorical data, and you are handling it as if it was numeric data.

In Machine Learning you would replace the missing values with the most common categorical value regarding a target attribute (*what you want to predict*).

*Example*: You want to predict if a person is male or female by looking at their car, and the color feature has some missing values. If most of the cars from male(female) drivers are blue(red), you would use that value to fill missing entries of cars from male(female) drivers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Basically I have no specific goal, It is a question for a post MSc course. I have a dataset and must explain which is the best way to proceed in this case

Comment: If there is no specific goal, I would not change the dataset at all. There could be a good reason why certain values are missing. So you would eventually take away information out of the data by changing it.

To keep the car example: What if someone does not own a car. Then of course it has no color resulting in a missing value. Replacing it with some value leads to wrong results (here: the assumption that the guy has a car). 

Missing values doesn't necessarily mean missing information.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest strategy for handling missing data is to remove records that contain a missing value.

The [scikit-learn](/questions/tagged/scikit-learn) library provides the `Imputer()` pre-processing class that can be used to replace missing values. Since it is categorical data, using the mean as a replacement value is not recommended. You can use

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imp = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='most_frequent', axis=0)
```

The Imputer class operates directly on the [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy) array instead of the DataFrame.

Last but not least, not ALL ML algorithms cannot handle missing values. Different implementations of ML are also different.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Lan's answer's approach, which seems most commonly used, you can use something based on matrix factorization. For example there is a variant of [Generalized Low Rank Models](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/papers/pdf/glrm.pdf) that can impute such data, just as probabilistic matrix factorization is used to impute continuous data.

[GLRMs can be used from H2O](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/10/docs-website/h2o-docs/data-science/glrm.html) which provides bindings for both Python and R.

Comment: Was going to suggest the same thing. Matrix factorization is a good general technique for matrix completion, which missing categorical data can be considered in some sense. It may or may not work that well in a particular case, but is worth trying.